# displaying a hiddden div1 when there is a change of text in div2

Tags: jquery

I have 2 divs `div#itemDetails`, `div#regCodeTarget` and a textfield `#regcode`. `div#itemDetails` is initially hiddent, after a registration code is entered in the text field `#regcode` and the code is correct, a text *Correct Key* is displayed in the `div#regCodeTarget`, when this happens `div#itemDetails` should also display immediately. This is the code below:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#itemDetails").hide();
  jQuery('#regcode').on('keydown', function() {
    if (jQuery('#regCodeTarget').text() == "Correct Key") {
      jQuery("#itemDetails").show();
    }
  });
});
```

But instead there is a delay, the div `div#itemDetails` only shows after entering the registration key and clicking another random button but the idea is for it to show after I have clicked the last letter on the registration code when the words *Correct Key* appear immediately.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `jQuery('#regCodeTarget').text()` should be `.val()` if it's an `input` field

Comment: Show your HTML so we can make a fiddle, or do that

Comment: Also, you need to show us where you call `jQuery('#regCodeTarget').text("Correct Key")` why not just call `jQuery("#itemDetails").show();` when you set the text to "Correct Key"? Testing for the text you just set seems like bad design

Comment: Please click `<>`  and create a [mcve]

Comment: Try using "keyup" event instead of "keydown"

Comment: @NisheshPratap there is no reason to think that would solve this issue

Comment: '<div id="code">
  <input name="regCode" id="regcode" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="ajax('bMarket', ['regCode'], 'regCodeTarget')" placeholder="Enter Registration Code" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="This code is a 20 character code that allows you to register your product with SesowA&trade;. It is for sale, it costs P100.00. Sms RegCode to 76135061 to get your registration code."/><br />
    <div id="regCodeTarget"></div>
        </div>'

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
<p id="itemDetails">This is test</p>
<p id="regCodeTarget">Correct Key</p>
<input type="text" id="regcode">

<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#itemDetails").hide();
      jQuery('#regcode').on('keyup', function() {
        if (jQuery('#regCodeTarget').text() == "Correct Key" && jQuery(this).val() == jQuery('#regCodeTarget').text()) {
          jQuery("#itemDetails").show();
        }else{
          jQuery("#itemDetails").hide();
        }
      });
   });
</script>
```